# SwiftUI | Is there a way to set MKCoordinateSpan dynamically to show an annotation and userLocation?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit

---

I have a hard time trying to find anything about "dynamic zoom" to show all **annotations + userLocation** on the `SwiftUI Map` view via `MapKit`.

- what I have: [My best effort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uOkJ.jpg)
- what I'd love: [What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvvbw.jpg)

Right now I only set the `MKCoordinateSpan` inside the `MKCoordinateRegion` to `MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.175, longitudeDelta: 0.175)`

MKCoordinateRegion inside my viewModel:

```
@Published var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.789467, longitude: -122.416772), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.175, longitudeDelta: 0.175))
```

My Map inside the View:

```
Map(coordinateRegion: self.$region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true,
                userTrackingMode: self.$userTrackingMode, annotationItems: self.buildings) { (location) -> MapMarker in
                MapMarker(coordinate: location.coordinate, tint: R.color.denim)
            }
            .toSquare(side: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32)
            .commonRoundedCorners()
```

Comment: You need to put all of your annotations and the user location in an array.  Then find the minimum and maximum latitudes and longitudes of the entries.  This gives you the four corners of your region.  From that you can easily compute the center and span

Comment: Thank you! Got it working now! Have a great day. :)